# Why is requestAnimationFrame generating "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I am JavaScript beginner and I had some code that was working perfectly in terms of functionality but it was so ***not*** DRY and "dirty"... just looking at that code was making me sick. 
So, I decided to do a very nice, modern, clean and DRY version. 
But now I'm totally stuck and despite searching high and low can't find anything to understand WHAT EXACTLY am I doing wrong? 
And most importantly: **WHY is it wrong?**

So, here's the current code:

```js
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // parent div that holds the navigation wheel: 
            var navDiv = document.querySelector("#wrapper > section > div");
            navDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", moveEye, false);
            navDiv.addEventListener("mouseup", stopEye, false);
            
            var eye = document.querySelector("#eyeball"),
                iris = document.querySelector("#iris"),
                reqID;
            
            function moveEye(e) {
                var btnClicked = e.target.id;
//                alert("Button clicked: " + btnClicked);
                if (btnClicked === "right") {
                    eye.style.left = (eye.offsetLeft += 3) + "px";
                } else if (btnClicked === "left") {
                    eye.style.left = (eye.offsetLeft -= 3) + "px";
                } else if (btnClicked === "top") {
                    eye.style.top = (eye.offsetTop -= 3) + "px";
                } else if (btnClicked === "bottom") {
                    eye.style.top = (eye.offsetTop += 3) + "px";
                }

                reqID = window.requestAnimationFrame(moveEye);
            }
            
            function stopEye(e) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(reqID);
            }
            
        }, false);
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p>Description comes here.</p>
        <section>
            <p>Navigation Wheel:</p>
            <div>
                <span id="top"></span>
                <span id="bottom"></span>
                <span id="left"></span>
                <span id="right"></span>
                <span id="hub"></span>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="stage">
            <figure id="eyeball">
                <span id="shadow"></span>
                <span id="iris" class="irisMove"></span>
            </figure>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Note that I specifically want to **keep** this:

```
var navDiv = document.querySelector("#wrapper > section > div");
```

because I want to keep the code as DRY and as clean as I can manage. 
That's why I'm selecting the **parent** div that holds the 4 buttons 
and NOT each of the 4 buttons individually. 
So, I want to listen to the parent div to tell me which of the 4 buttons (i.e. the 4 span elements) inside is currently being clicked down and while the user is holding the mouse down on the button/span I want the requestAnimationFrame to do its darn job! 
That's it! Not too much asked, right?

But as I understand at the moment it's the darn requestAnimationFrame that causes this error: 
**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"**

And the big question is: WHY???
Why is requestAnimationFrame saying that it's "undefined"??
It works fine without bringing requestAnimationFrame into play here.

So, please explain: 
What exactly am I doing wrong? 
And most importantly: 
Why is it wrong?

Comment: Please make that example easier for us to test. CSS, images, and such. Note that spans don't get heights or widths, or margins on top or bottom, as they are inline elements. Consider `inline-block` or floated `block` level Elements.

Comment: P.S. I sorta managed to understand before asking the question that requestAnimationFrame isn't passing the "e". 
But without the "e" the whole thing is gonna be dead in the water. 
So, what's the solution for this conundrum?

Comment: @PHPglue 
How can I add CSS afterwards? I'm trying but the editor is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(moveEye);
```

...is going to cause `moveEye` to be called, sort of like this:

```
moveEye(timestamp);
```

Notice there's no event being passed, but a timestamp instead. So `e.target` in the function is going to be undefined, which is why `e.target.id` fails.

If your intent is to do an animation loop, you need to "capture" the relevant data. A closure would make this possible:

```
function moveEye(e) {
  var btnClicked = e.target.id;
  function animate() {
    if (btnClicked === "right") {
      eye.style.left = (eye.offsetLeft += 3) + "px";
    } else if (btnClicked === "left") {
      eye.style.left = (eye.offsetLeft -= 3) + "px";
    } else if (btnClicked === "top") {
      eye.style.top = (eye.offsetTop -= 3) + "px";
    } else if (btnClicked === "bottom") {
      eye.style.top = (eye.offsetTop += 3) + "px";
    }
    reqID = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  animate();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this was sorta already clear to me. I managed to figure that much out.
But the question is WHY??? 
Or to put it another way: 
How can I pass that "e" thingy along?
Because without it ain't gonna work.

Comment: It's because the Event Object is now being passed to the function that is run in `requestAnimationFrame()`. You could also just change: `reqID = window.requestAnimationFrame(moveEye);` to `reqID = requestAnimationFrame(function(){ moveEye(e); });` instead of the above technique. Yes, you can leave `window` off, as it is implicit in JavaScript that methods not overwritten by you are a property of `window`. Of course, the Event Object is your issue with the code.

Comment: @Jacob Man, thank you so much! It would only be a slight exaggeration to say that you saved my life! I sure do need to learn about closures. Having no idea about that subject caused me many hours of despair.

Comment: @WebDevBooster glad I could help! Thanks for the positive words.

Answer (score 1):

When `moveEye` is called in response to a mouse click, it is provided with an event object as first argument. The event object has a `target` property.

When `moveEye` is called as a callback from `requestAnimationFrame`, it is passed a [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) double precision number. JavaScript allows attempts to access properties on a number by automatically converting it to a Number object.

However, Number objects don't have a `target` property, so the value returned from the property lookup is `undefined`. Now trying to access the `id` property of an undefined `target` property generates the error.

---

**Update**
Naturally a fix requires using separate functions for the click event handler and animation callback. After attending to other issues here's a working example that moves #eyeball:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // parent div that holds the navigation wheel: 
    var navDiv = document.querySelector("#wrapper > section > div");
    navDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", startEye, false);
    navDiv.addEventListener("mouseup", stopEye, false);

    var eye = document.querySelector("#eyeball"),
        iris = document.querySelector("#iris"),
        reqID,
        btnClicked = "";

    function startEye(e) {
        btnClicked = e.target.id;
        moveEye();
    }
    function moveEye() {
        var left = parseFloat( eye.style.left);
        var top = parseFloat( eye.style.top);

        if ( btnClicked === "right") {
          eye.style.left = (left + 3) + "px";
        } 
        else if ( btnClicked === "left") {
          eye.style.left = (left -3) + 'px';
        }
        else if ( btnClicked === "top") {
            eye.style.top = (top - 3) + "px";
        }
        else if ( btnClicked === "bottom") {
            eye.style.top = (top + 3) + "px";
        }
        reqID = window.requestAnimationFrame(moveEye);
    }
    
    function stopEye(e) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(reqID);
    }
    
},false);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<p>Description comes here.</p>
<section>
    <p>Navigation Wheel:</p>
    <div>
        <span id="top">top</span>
        <span id="bottom">bottom</span>
        <span id="left">left</span>
        <span id="right">right</span>
        <span id="hub"></span>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="stage">
    <figure id="eyeball" style="position: relative; top:0px; left: 0px">
        eyeball
        <span id="shadow"></span>
        <span id="iris" class="irisMove"></span>
    </figure>
</section>
</div>
```

**TLDR;**

Note that `.offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` are read-only element properties. Expressions like `(eye.offsetTop += 3)` or `(eye.offsetLeft -= 3)` don't update the value of the property, are seriously misleading and should not be left in the code.

CSS properties `left`/`top` and element properties `offSetLeft`/`offsetTop` don't use the same reference origin. Initially this caused clicking "left" to move the element rightwards as well. The solution adopted was to style the element to be moved (#eyeball)  with CSS `left` and `top`properties and using them to both  read and update position. This is why `offSetLeft` and `.offsetTop` are not used in the example.

Comment: OK, I understand now that my approach is fundamentally flawed.
But: 
Being a **beginner** I still have no idea what is actually the correct approach to solve this problem?